# When value changes in a cell in excel, add the new value to a table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for presumably a VBA script. Basically the situation is this: I have a sheet that automatically fetches values from an API so whenever I update the sheet the values change. What I want to do is add the new values from certain cells to a table on another sheet. So whenever the values change, the new value is added to the first empty row in a certain column. I'd like to keep track of historical data to follow how these values develop over time. A nice bonus would be adding the exact time of that specific update to a different column on the same row but I can do that manually as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use these Macros to track the changes in particular Data Range.**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:B100")) Is Nothing Then
Call Master
End If
End Sub
```

**Note:**

- This code will Run **Macro (Master)** when any 
  cell value changes in the Range.

*Enter below written VBA code as standard Module.*

- This code will copy every New/Altered value from range `A1:B100` in to the New Sheet `MasterSheet` without over write old records.

  ```
  Sub Master()

  Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
  Dim sourceRange As Range
  Dim sourceRows As Integer

  Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

  sourceRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(sourceSheet.Range("A:A"))

  Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A1:B" & sourceRows)

  Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
  Dim targetRange As Range
  Dim targetRows As Integer

  Set targetSheet = Worksheets("MasterSheet")

  targetRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(targetSheet.Range("A:A"))

  Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("A" & targetRows + 1 & ":B" & targetRows + 1 + sourceRows)

  sourceRange.Copy Destination:=targetRange

  End Sub
  ```

**Note:**

- For Better Data & File Management I've used two MACRO.
- Macro uses the `COUNTA` to work out how may rows are in use.
- If you have column headings on the Source sheet and the Master then they'll get duplicated. So you might want to make the `sourceRange` start at `A2`.

*Adjust Cell references and Sheet name as needed.*

Comment: This seems about right but I still have some issues. I probably wasn't completely clear in my original post so sorry for that. From what I gather your code adds any changed values in that specific range to the end of column A on the MasterSheet. However that's not quite what I'm looking for. Let's say cell A2 is value x and B2 is value y. When value x changes I'd like to add that to column A on a different sheet. A1 would be the heading "value x" and that column only includes previous values of value x. When I change value y in the original sheet that would go to column B on the second sheet.

Comment: @RasmusTieaho, I've suggested solution based on the OP, what I would like to suggest since my code is observing all  changes into Source Sheet and updates to another, and it could be modified as per your recent needs, so use it and do required correction ☺

Comment: @Rasmus You cannot change the question after somebody already spent time and effort answering. Please give proper credit to the answer you have got, if you think it answers your original written question. You can post a new question, that better reflects your actual problem.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, you raised a good point. OP must be very careful while posting,, and frequent changes deviates the answerer. ☺

Comment: Alright, was not aware of this.